# how to set value to property [name , age] using the type Proxied<Cat>

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I was trying to figure out how to assign values to the [age, name] property using set (), but it shows me an error that you can see below.

If there is a way to correct the error, I will appreciate it.

**index.ts**

```js
interface Proxy<T>{
  get(): T;
  set(value: T): void;
}

type Proxied<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Proxy<T[P]>;
}

interface Cat{
  age: number;
  name: string;
}


type PC = Proxied<Cat>;

const doc: PC = null;

doc.age.set(1);
console.log(doc.age.get())
```

**error**

```sh
C:\Users\c\Desktop\typetify\src\typetify.ts:3
  set(value: T): void;
    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\c\Desktop\typetify\src\typetify.ts:3:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\c\Desktop\typetify\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:858:23)    
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\c\Desktop\typetify\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:861:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at main (C:\Users\c\Desktop\typetify\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:227:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\c\Desktop\typetify\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:513:3)      
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Types don't generate code. You need to create a proxy Factory function that returns proxy objects. You also need to create an object to proxy in the first place which you haven't done. You have a value that is null and you try to treat it like a proxy cat

Comment: it is worth noting that this isn't really a proxy because it's not transparent. It has to be accessed differently than what it proxies. What's your use case?